# How to load properties from two different locales-specific files in a single page in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, locale

The resource-bundle is configured as-

```
    <resource-bundle>                        
        <base-name>views.msgs.labels</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
```

in `faces-config.xml`.

with 2 properties files in `resources/views/msgs/` -

```
labels_en.properties
labels_fr.properties
```

There are 2 sections:

In the above section, the text/ labels need to be shown in `English`, whereas the lower half, the text has to appear in `French`.

To put it simple,

```
  <f:view locale="en" >            
            #{msg['hello']}
            #{msg['name']}
  </f:view>
  <f:view locale="fr" >            
            #{msg['HELLO']}
            #{msg['name']}
  </f:view>
```

The two keys `hello` & `name` appears in both property files.

I see that `locale="fr"` in the lower half `f:view` overrides the above one.

And the whole output appears in `French`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This construct is not supported. The `<f:view>` represents the `UIViewRoot`. Whilst there can be multiple `<f:view>` tags, there can be only one `UIViewRoot` instance in the component tree. The attributes of the latter `<f:view>` declaration would override any previously declared one.

Your best bet is manually loading the resource bundle via [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) API the usual way and assigning it a different variable name in EL.

Easiest would be to use a managed bean for that. E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Labels {

    private ResourceBundle french;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        french = ResourceBundle.getBundle("views.msgs.labels", Locale.FRENCH);
    }

    public ResourceBundle getFrench() {
        return french;
    }

}
```

*(hint: you can get the [`<default-locale>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getDefaultLocale--) and all [`<supported-locale>`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getSupportedLocales--) via [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html))*

Then use it as below:

```html
Current locale:
#{msg['hello']}
#{msg['name']}

French locale:
#{labels.french['HELLO']}
#{labels.french['name']}
```

#### See also:

- [Read resource bundle properties in a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655540/read-i18n-variables-from-properties-file-in-a-bean/)
- [Getting Message from all resource files in different locale from a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743510/getting-message-from-all-resource-files-in-different-locale-from-a-key/)
- [Injecting ResourceBundle via @ManagedProperty doesn't seem to work inside @Named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045667/injecting-resourcebundle-via-managedproperty-doesnt-seem-to-work-inside-named/)